# Mock Multiplayer techniques on Android / iOS

Tags: android, ios, game-center, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am building a turnbased multiplayer word game. Is it feasible to create mock users using Google Player Game Services / Game Center / any other service, or would I have to roll my own server? How do other apps/games do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't change the built-in waiting room UI, you can implement your own if you like!

There is nothing magical about our particular UI -- it's just implemented using the standard API that's available to everybody.

So to implement your own waiting room, you'd have to implement the [RoomStatusUpdateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomStatusUpdateListener.html) and the [RoomUpdateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomUpdateListener.html) and reflect the changes on your UI. When you decide that it's time to start the game (for example, when a sufficient number of players is connected), you can hide your waiting room UI and start playing the game.